# Apache Tomcat precompile JSPs before first request

Tags: jsp, tomcat

Is there any option in Apache Tomcat Web Server, to **compile the JSPs in a WAR at deploy time**, instead of the first request instance.

So that, when a user requests it for the first time he should not get a performance lag.

We are using Apache Tomcat 5

Answer (score 1):

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jasper-howto.html

A simple google search gave me this answer....

Comment: He was asking about compiling all jsps at deploy time not at compile time

Answer (score 0):

You can not compile all JSPs at deploy time. You can only pre compile them at compile time with a build tool like ant, maven or gradle (or whatever you prefer).